# How to Prefix Sub-directory Containing Controllers in Routes?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-5.4

I have Prefixed `admin` URI Using Route Groups, but I also want to Prefix `admin` Directory Containing Controllers I want to use!

Let's make it simple. Here is the Route File.

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function(){

    Route::get('/',"Admin\HomeController@index");

    Route::get('settings',"Admin\HomeController@getSettings");
    Route::post('settings',"Admin\HomeController@postSettings");

    Route::get('users',"Admin\UserController@index");

    Route::get('invoices',"Admin\InvoiceController@index");
});
```

Every Time I write new Route, I have to define `Admin\` Directory to make Call the Controller Method.

Is there any way to Prefix the Subdirectory containing controllers too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the namespace within the group too

```html
Route::group( ['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'admin'], function(){
  Route::get('/',"HomeController@index");
  
  Route::get('settings',"HomeController@getSettings");
  Route::post('settings',"HomeController@postSettings");

  Route::get('users',"UserController@index");

  Route::get('invoices',"InvoiceController@index");
});
```